# Binding Setter value in a style in a resource dictionary

Tags: wpf, xaml, binding, microsoft-metro, resourcedictionary

I'm trying to create an app that uses skins/themes (different color pallets the use can choose from).

I define a `SolidColorBrush` property

```
public class ThemeManager
{
    public SolidColorBrush ForeBrush { get; set; }       

    public ThemeManager()
    {
        ForeBrush = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Black);         
    }

    public void SetTheme()
    {        
        ForeBrush.Color = Colors.Red;
    }
}
```

and bind it in XAML

```
<TextBlock Foreground="{Binding ForeBrush,Source={StaticResource Theme}}" />
```

I declare the Theme resource in App.xaml

```
<local:ThemeManager x:Key="Theme" />
```

The problem is when I make a style like:

```
<Style x:Key="TextBlockStyle1" TargetType="TextBlock">
     <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="{Binding ForeBrush,Source={StaticResource Theme}}" />
</Style>
```

This works if I place it in `Page.Resources`, but if I place it in a Resource Dictionary (and add it to App.xaml) the app crashes ( Debugger.Break() in App.g.i.cs). 
This only seems to happen when using a Setter.

What am I doing wrong here?

EDIT:
placing the style in a Resource Dictionary file and referencing that in app.xaml

Comment: This code works on my PC with .Net 4.0. What version of .NET are you using?

Comment: @Klaus78 I've tested the code both in .Net 5 (metro-style app) and wpf .Net 4.0. Did you add the style in a dictionary and referenced it in app.xaml ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With this code it works on my PC (with .NET 4.0)

Here is the Dictionary

```
<ResourceDictionary xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
                xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
                xmlns:local="clr-namespace:Resources4">
<local:ThemeManager x:Key="Theme"></local:ThemeManager>
<Style TargetType="TextBlock">
    <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="{Binding ForeBrush,Source={StaticResource  Theme}}" />
</Style>
</ResourceDictionary>
```

Here is the reference in XAML

```
<Application.Resources>
    <ResourceDictionary>
        <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
            <ResourceDictionary Source="Dictionary1.xaml"></ResourceDictionary>
        </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
    </ResourceDictionary>
</Application.Resources>
```

If you write

```
<Application.Resources>
    <ResourceDictionary>
        <local:ThemeManager x:Key="Theme" />
        <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
            <ResourceDictionary Source="Dictionary1.xaml" />
        </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
    </ResourceDictionary>
</Application.Resources>
```

Then you get an error because of how merged resource dictionary works.
According to [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa350178.aspx)

> Resources in a merged dictionary occupy a location in the resource lookup scope that is just after the scope of the main resource dictionary they are merged into

This means that in Dictionary1.xaml it is not possible to see a resource defined in App.XAML

Comment: hmm, yes that works, i just need to make the class a singleton. but i'm still curious to why     
<Application.Resources>
  <ResourceDictionary>    
     <local:ThemeManager x:Key="Theme" />
       <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>                
         <ResourceDictionary Source="Dictionary1.xaml" />
            </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
        </ResourceDictionary>
    </Application.Resources>
doesn't work

Comment: Great! Adding the theme manager to separate resource dictionary and then merging it in app.xaml solves everything. Thanks